# Keep FFMPEG running and waiting for new image files to encode and stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting TIFF images to HTTP Live Stream. The images are being continuously streamed by a camera and saved to hard drive. FFMPEG is then converting the files to MPEG transport stream (.ts) and segmenting them. However, as soon as FFMPEG runs out of currently saved images to disk, it ends the conversion. Is there a way how I could keep FFMPEG running and waiting for new images to be saved to disk and converting them?

This is what I am using:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10/1 -i MMseries_%3d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -b:v 256000 -flags 
    -global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 
    -segment_list demo_list.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts video_seg_%05d.ts
```

Comment: What command line are you currently using to encode the TIFF images?

Comment: This is what I am using: ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10/1 -i MMseries_%3d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -b:v 256000 -flags -global_header -map 0 -f segment
-segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list demo_list.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts  video_seg_%05d.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try restricting ffmpeg to reading at source framerate i.e.

```
ffmpeg -re -f image2 -framerate 10 -i MMseries_%3d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 
       -b:v 256000 -flags +global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 4 
       -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list demo_list.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts
        video_seg_%05d.ts
```