# Continuous live stream from images

Tags: android, ios, encoding, video-streaming, video-codecs

I would like to make an application that is live streaming (HTTP Live Streaming) images that are continuously being generated by a camera (e.g. tiff files saved to disk). 
First I wanted to do this with FFMPEG ([Keep FFMPEG running and waiting for new image files to encode and stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383560/keep-ffmpeg-running-and-waiting-for-new-image-files-to-encode-and-stream)) unfortunately this is not possible as FFMPEG will stop once it goes through all the available images in the conversion location and does not keep waiting for my camera generating new images.

I am now considering writing my own application that would be doing this. Can you, please, recommend the best way to achieve this, encoders to use (x264?), segmenters etc.,  or any codec/protocol that is commonly used for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stream why don't you give a shot to VLC.

VLC does streaming nicely, I have done in Windows Platform and have used it across platforms.

Comment: Thanks, but does VLC create stream from images being constantly saved to disk?

Comment: That can be worth trying, I think it is doable but give a try.